# SQL Server Query gives ASP error

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a series of SQL Queries that work fine in the query analyser online, but I am struggling to adapt them for my asp page to run.

the query is ...

```
SELECT part1 AS 'idParts',
       count(*) AS 'Total' INTO #TempTable
FROM T_Jobs
WHERE MONTH(Date) = 1
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2015
GROUP BY part1
UNION
SELECT part2 AS 'idParts',
       count(*) AS 'Total'
FROM T_Jobs
WHERE MONTH(Date) = 1
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2015
GROUP BY part2
UNION
SELECT part3 AS 'idParts',
       count(*) AS 'Total'
FROM T_Jobs
WHERE MONTH(Date) = 1
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2015
GROUP BY part3
DELETE
FROM #TempTable
WHERE idParts = 'Select Part:'
  SELECT #TempTable.idParts,#TempTable.Total,
                             T_Parts.partCost INTO #TempTable2
  FROM #TempTable
  JOIN T_Parts ON #TempTable.idParts=T_Parts.idParts
  SELECT Sum(Total*partCost) AS RESULT
  FROM #TempTable2
```

this returns the total cost of all the parts used for that month, having retrieved the parts list from one table and the relevant price for that part from another.

But how would I put that into an asp page so I can oConn.Execute(strSQL) it to display the 'Result' from #TempTable2 please?

I just can't seem to work out the correct syntax for the strSQL to execute it.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can't you put the SQL into a stored procedure and simply call the stored procedure?

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work?  The syntax doesn't change, you'd still just be executing a SQL statement like any other.

Comment: I guess you want to do UNION ALL, not UNION. (In case equal results from the different select's...)

Comment: Have you viewed the actual command your trying to execute on your page? I would be the single quotations within your query are closing  the query string prematurely.

Comment: hi Rhys. I am not hiding the fact that I am no expert at sql queries! lol. I have not explored stored procedures previously as my most complex queries have been simple select and sum type single line efforts. I appreciate your advice and will look into stored procedures right now to see if It will solve my problem :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 strSQL = "select part1 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' into #TempTable from     T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = 1 AND YEAR(Date) = 2015 group by part1 " &
"UNION " &
 "select part2 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' from T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = 1 AND YEAR(Date) = 2015 group by part2 " &
 "UNION " &
 "select part3 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' from T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = 1 AND YEAR(Date) = 2015 group by part3 " &
 "GO " &
 "delete from #TempTable where idParts = 'Select Part:' " &
 "GO " &
 "select #TempTable.idParts,#TempTable.Total,T_Parts.partCost into #TempTable2 from #TempTable join T_Parts on #TempTable.idParts=T_Parts.idParts "  &
 "GO " &
 "select Sum(Total*partCost) as Result from #TempTable2 "
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that answer, however I get "incorrect syntax near the keyword delete" error

Comment: hi. I used this answer but the GO gave incorrect syntax, so at these points I split it into 4 separate queries and made the temp table semi-permanent with ##TempTable so I could reference it across separate queries., with that done, it works a treat. thank you.

Comment: Good.  I am glad it helped.  Breaking it into 4 separate queries is a good idea, but make sure to clean up your ##TempTable when complete.

Answer (score 0):

ok solved ... here's how I did it (with your help!)

I had to split the query into 4 parts and make the temp table a semi permanent one so that I could reference it between different queries.

strSQL = "select part1 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' into ##TempTable from T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = " & exp_month & " AND YEAR(Date) = " & exp_year & " group by part1 " & "UNION ALL " & "select part2 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' from T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = " & exp_month & " AND YEAR(Date) = " & exp_year & " group by part2 " & "UNION ALL " & "select part3 as 'idParts',count(*) as 'Total' from T_Jobs where MONTH(Date) = " & exp_month & " AND YEAR(Date) = " & exp_year & " group by part3 "

strSQL2 = "delete from ##TempTable where idParts = 'Select Part:' "

strSQL3 = "select ##TempTable.idParts,##TempTable.Total,T_Parts.partCost into ##TempTable2 from ##TempTable join T_Parts on ##TempTable.idParts=T_Parts.idParts "

strSQL4 = "select Sum(Total*partCost) as Result from ##TempTable2 "

the exp_month and exp_year variables are from the referring form so I can select the date to view.

works a treat. thank you for all your help.